# Dynamic html5 audio flash player

Tags: ajax, flash, html, html5-audio, fallback

Does there exist a library / program that can play mp3 files using flash as html5 fallback dynamically?

By dynamically, I mean that the player can switch the current mp3 thats playing, even after dom has loaded. The problem I run into with most flash audio players is that they depend on the song being loaded when the dom loads, but my website loads songs through ajax.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new HTML5 audio library called [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/). Looks pretty slick!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) which is quite powerful. It plays both audio and video and I've used it myself for both. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of all free html5 players.

[List Of html5 players](http://www.jquery4u.com/media/10-jquery-html5-audio-players/)

I have tried almost all but i think http://mediaelementjs.com/ is best.